# How to parse the dates in a data frame directly instead of using the parse_dates parameter while reading the excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

The following is one way of converting string dates into timestamps :

```
df = pd.read_excel("path/filename.xlsx", parse_dates=["Date"], inplace=True)
```

Is there a way to parse these dates in a dataframe that contains these dates as a string instead of doing it via the read_excel function?

The input is an excel file containing the following data:

```
    Name    Date
    AA      01-JAN-2016
    BB      02-JAN-2016
```

Now these dates are of type string. I want to parse them after reading them into a dataframe. Here is the attempt :

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
s=list(df['Date'])
type(s[1])
```

The output turns out to be str.

Comment: Do you mean [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)?

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo Well, that is a way that is constantly coming on the internet. But this code isn't working either : pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

Comment: Could you add an input example where it doesnt work?

Comment: The input is an excel file containing the following data:
    Name   Date
    AA        01-JAN-2016
    BB        02-JAN-2016
Now these dates are of type string. I want to parse them after reading them. Here is the attempt : 
pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
s=list(df['Date'])
type(s[1])
The output turns out to be str.

Comment: I have edited my question for more clarity